@msal-browser loginPopup() The provided request must include a 'client_secret' input parameter
I am trying to get the auth token for configuring online MsTeams Meeting. It shows the the loginpopup window when i click continue i get
The provided request must include a 'client_secret' input parameter. -> error
 const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
          clientId
        }
      };
      const scopes = {
        scopes: ['user.read', 'OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite']
      };
      const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
      await msalInstance.initialize();
      const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(scopes);


The error

The provided request must include a 'client_secret' input parameter"

usually occurs if you are making use of public client authentication and not enabled public client flows.
If you are making use of public client authentication, then you should not pass client secret.
Hence to resolve the error, in the Microsoft Entra ID application enable public client flows like below:

Make sure to add the redirect URL in Mobile and desktop applications if you are using mobile application:

